What keysize can I use to get an Ed25519 KeyPairGenerator instance?
I'm trying to get a KeyPairGenerator instance for Ed25519.
I'd also like to provide an explicit SecureRandom instance. There's an initialize method that accepts an int, the keysize, and a SecureRandom.
What value can I pass as a keysize argument?
KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("Ed25519");
SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom();
int keysize = 123; /* what's an appropriate value? */

keyPairGenerator.initialize(keysize, secureRandom);

KeyPair keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();

The above throws
Exception in thread "main" java.security.InvalidParameterException: Unsupported size: 123
    at jdk.crypto.ec/sun.security.ec.ParametersMap$1.get(ParametersMap.java:78)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:403)
    at jdk.crypto.ec/sun.security.ec.ParametersMap.getBySize(ParametersMap.java:102)
    at jdk.crypto.ec/sun.security.ec.ed.EdDSAParameters.getBySize(EdDSAParameters.java:312)
    at jdk.crypto.ec/sun.security.ec.ed.EdDSAKeyPairGenerator.initialize(EdDSAKeyPairGenerator.java:75)
    at java.base/java.security.KeyPairGenerator$Delegate.initialize(KeyPairGenerator.java:671)

So what is an appropriate value?

Ed25519 keys are fixed to 32 bytes (calling initialize is unnecessary). It's not clear what you're asking, what you think keysize is in this context.

Ed25519 is defined in RFC 8032. As you can see, and as the previous comment notes, the key size is 32 bytes == 256 bits. However, the order of the subgroup that operations are conducted in is about 2^252, so the strength is more life 252/2 == 126 bits.

Ed25519 keys are fixed to 32 bytes - true, and it is NOT working value, as well as 256 bits.

I created this question and answer, as here you must take 255!

calling initialize is necessary, as I use an other source for random. new SecureRandom() is here only as example. I use a modified SP800SecureRandom,

@PresidentJamesK.Polk 32 bytes is the size of the representation of the private key. That is not in general the same thing as the “key size”, which is generally the size of some number or bit-string associated with the key.

See the Javadoc for KeyPairGeneratorSpi

In case the client does not explicitly initialize the KeyPairGenerator (via a call to an initialize method), each provider must supply (and document) a default initialization. See the Keysize Restriction sections of the JDK Providers document for information on the KeyPairGenerator defaults used by JDK providers. However, note that defaults may vary across different providers. Additionally, the default value for a provider may change in a future version. Therefore, it is recommended to explicitly initialize the KeyPairGenerator instead of relying on provider-specific defaults.

The SunEC Provider described in the linked document supports Ed25519 .
Under Keysize Restrictions for the various supported algorithms, it states that the "Default Keysize" for Ed25519 is 255. It additionally states the following restriction

Keysize must be 255

In other words, the only valid value is 255.
keyPairGenerator.initialize(255, secureRandom);

Alternatively, since this value is fixed, you shouldn't need to provide it. Instead, use the initialize overload that accepts an AlgorithmParameterSpec and pass the corresponding NamedParameterSpec. For example,
keyPairGenerator.initialize(NamedParameterSpec.ED25519, new SecureRandom());


Solution see code:
KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("Ed25519");
keyPairGenerator.initialize(255,new SecureRandom());
KeyPair keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();

Solution found using the debugger: keysize=32, bits=255
The answer is 255!

How did the debugger tell you that?

sun.security.ec.ed.EdDSAParameters line 53 this.keyLength=32 and line 54 this.bits=255 at runtime (Idea IDE with breakpoint on this.keyLength).

as the name is Curve25519 it may a hint that 255 is the right one.

25519 compactly describes the prime the curve is defined over (2^255 - 19). I wouldn't call 255 the key size and those class variable names don't really do it either.

public void initialize(int keysize, SecureRandom random) makes it difficult, as this value is not ignored and has to be 255. The value 255 is the one and only valid value for Curve25519 here.

Also, sun.security.ec.ed.EdDSAOperations.generatePrivate(SecureRandom random) generates a 32 byte array with 256 bits of entropy, not 255.

@PresidentJamesK.Polk The amount of entropy is completely irrelevant. Picking 255 as “the key size” for Curve25519 and Ed25519 is common: it's the size of the numbers over which the algorithm works (coordinates on the curve).
